# multiple monitors, how do i wake one but keep others sleeping

Tags: c#, multiple-monitors

if i have a system with multiple monitors, and they're all sleeping, is there a way, if i shake the mouse, to only wake one up and keep the others sleeping? in c#? I looked into the windows "screen" class but there's no methods for waking or sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

Monitors sleeping is an OS function (usually, it means that the computer has been inactive for a time). I am not sure that windows, or any other operating system allows this kind of low level meddling (to change the definition of wake to be screen specific).

Comment: look here [link](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=249459).i want the monitors to sleep/wake only one, not all.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a feature you can control at the application level.  And if you think about it, it is not really a workable model for interacting with multiple screens that represent a single desktop.

- Does each monitor now have its own notion of inactivity?
- Does the user have to continually keep mousing over to inactive displays to wake them up?
- Should the rest of a big display be blanked out if we aren't using the whole display?

A central idea of the desktop is that when it is not suspended you could be looking at anything on it, even an inactive window and that window might be on a secondary display.  It's either all or nothing: all displays are suspended or none of them are.  You can **disable** secondary displays but that changes your desktop configuration.